# Easiest way to re-arrange data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

There are a million and one plus sites for teaching data wrangling and organization in R, but I'm not sure what will be the most efficient given my problem/ I know how to do this easily in python, but what's an equivalent easy way to do this in R?

Say, for example, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ROI <- c("a_01","a_02","a_03","b_01","b_02","b_03")
summer_1 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
winter_1 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
summer_2 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
winter_2 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
summer_3 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
winter_3 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
summer_4 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
winter_4 <- runif(6, min=0, max=1)
df <- data.frame(ROI,summer_1,winter_1,summer_2,winter_2,summer_3,winter_3,summer_4,winter_4)

> head(df)

ROI   summer_1 winter_1 summer_2 winter_2 summer_3 winter_3 summer_4 winter_4
a_01  0.29930  0.65683  0.37349  0.88818  0.35568 0.95592 0.08095 0.07626
a_02  0.20637  0.91795  0.32142  0.81373  0.31344 0.92150 0.05090 0.04731
a_03  0.20925  0.92048  0.32336  0.155956 0.60364 0.155893 0.06320 0.05835
b_01  0.23676  0.108526 0.63557 0.92560  0.46017 0.76339 0.06265 0.05079
```

But I want to re-arrange the columns so that it looks like this:

```
ROI   no  season value
a     1   summer 81.33328 
a     2   summer 15.34663
...
```

and so forth

So far I have this:

```
library(stringr)
df$new <- str_split_fixed(dat$ROI, "_", 2)
```

How else can I best approach this?

Comment: Did you meant the 'no' coming from the 'ROI' column or from the suffix of 'season' columns

Comment: Good question! It should be from `ROI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
#split the 'ROI' into two columns
res <- separate(df, ROI, into = c("ROI", 'no'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
          #reshape from wide to long format 
          gather(season, value, summer_1:winter_2) %>%
          #split the season column into two
          separate(season, into = c('season', 'n')) %>%
          #remove the columns that are not needed
          select(-n)

head(res)
#  ROI no season    value
#1   a  1 summer 29.25740
#2   a  2 summer 22.48911
#3   a  3 summer 70.42230
#4   b  1 summer 51.88971
#5   b  2 summer 66.26196
#6   b  3 summer 92.04438
```

---

Or another option is to split the columns with `cSplit`, use `melt` from `data.table` to convert it to 'long' format

```
library(splitstackshape)
res2 <- setnames(melt(cSplit(df, "ROI", sep="_"), id.var = c("ROI_1", "ROI_2"), 
  variable.name = "season"), 1:2, c("ROI", "no"))[, season := sub("_\\d+", "", season)][]
head(res2)
#   ROI no season    value
#1:   a  1 summer 29.25740
#2:   a  2 summer 22.48911
#3:   a  3 summer 70.42230
#4:   b  1 summer 51.88971
#5:   b  2 summer 66.26196
#6:   b  3 summer 92.04438
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
ROI <- c("a_01","a_02","a_03","b_01","b_02","b_03")
summer_1 <- runif(6, min=0, max=100)
winter_1 <- runif(6, min=0, max=100)
summer_2 <- runif(6, min=0, max=100)
winter_2 <- runif(6, min=0, max=100)
df <- data.frame(ROI,summer_1,winter_1,summer_2,winter_2)
```

Comment: Ok, the error I'm getting is `Too many values at 7 locations: 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19`. In actuality the last column in my data frame is `winter_4`, so I changed the gather line to be: `gather(season, value, summer_1:winter_4) %>%`. Should I do something else?

Comment: @JAG2024 What is your tidyr version?   I am not finding any error with the example you showed.  I am using `tidyr_0.6.1`

Comment: I just downloaded `tidyverse` for the first time and it's 1.1.1

Comment: @JAG2024  Perhaps, there is a clash in the individual package versions and the one in tidyverse.

Comment: I'll download your version and try again.

Comment: I get this error: `Error in install_version("tidyverse", version = "0.6.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") : 
  version '0.6.1' is invalid for package 'tidyverse'`

Comment: @JAG2024  I meant that it is `tidyr` and not `tidyverse` (which is a collection of packages).  Perhaps you can remove the `tidyverse` and install packages separately

Comment: @JAG2024  I also updated with another option using `cSplit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143063/discussion-between-jag2024-and-akrun).